# Displaying icons for directories in zsh prompt

Tags: scripting, zsh, prompt

This is, roughly, my left prompt for zsh:

```bsh
# Libraries
autoload -Uz colors && colors

# User color
if [ "$(whoami)" = "root" ]; then
    COLOR="red"
elif [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    COLOR="magenta"
fi

# Directory icon
if [ "$()" = "Documents" ]; then
    ICON=""
if [ "$()" = "Pictures" ]; then
    ICON=""
if [ "$()" = "Videos" ]; then
    ICON=""
else
    ICON="%~"
fi

export PS1="%B%{$fg[$COLOR]%}$ICON %{$reset_color%}%b"
```

Instead of displaying

```bsh
~/Documents/git/project1 >>>
```

I want to display

```bsh
"ICON" git/project1 >>>
```

where `"ICON"` is an appropriate (predetermined) icon for the user's current directory. If the user is not in these "chosen" directories, simply display the relative path (like in my script).

How can this script read the user's current directory and determine what icon to display (or not display) to the terminal?

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question. Please [edit] it and make clear what problem you want to solve.

Comment: I just updated my question. Thanks for letting my know!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
typeset -A dir_to_icon
and_below='(|/*)'
dir_to_icon=(
  ~/Documents$and_below ''
  ~/Pictures$and_below  ''
  ~/Videos$and_below    ''
)

set_icon() {
  local found
  found=( ${(kv)dir_to_icon[(k)$PWD]} )
  psvar[1]= psvar[2]=
  (( $#found == 0 )) || psvar[1]=$found[2] psvar[2]=${PWD#$~found[1]}
}
chpwd_functions+=( set_icon )
PS1='%1(v|%(#.%F{red}.%F{magenta})%1v%f %2v|%~)$ '
```